# bad_alloc when inserting into unordered_map

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

In recent projects, stl unordermap is used. When the number of keys stored in the map rises to 6 times -7 times or even 8 times, the performance of the insert interface of unordermap has a serious bottleneck. As the number of inserted elements increases, collision occurs during the insert process. The collision opens to a certain threshold, triggering the increase of the bucket, which triggers the rehash. Printing the bucket_size can see that the bucketsize has been increasing, which is very expensive.

Here is the test code:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::unordered_map<int, int> t;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10000000; ++i) {
    t.insert(make_pair(i, 1));
    }
}
```

Should I use the number of reserved elements to improve performance?

```cpp
t.reserve(10000000)
```

Comment: The performace of `std::unordered_map` depends on several factors. Big bucket size means that the hash function is not very good or max load factor is very high. Can you post what is the `key` that you are using, hash function and what is the `max_load_factor`

Comment: What does your question have to do with bad_alloc? It is in the title but you never mention it again.

Comment: Is your question related to performance bottlenecks or specifically a bad_alloc when you're inserting elements?

Comment: @ZanLynx I am operating unordered_map in multithreading, I don't know if it is the reason, if the element is not reserved Program will be bad_alloc

Comment: @user1173240 I suspect that performance issues are causing bad_alloc

Comment: @qq234853008 Perhaps you can show the actual code, so the actual issue can be pinpointed, or at least a piece of code that is a reasonable approximation of the actual block. Looking at bits and pieces, and hearing about multithreading in comments doesn't help much.

Comment: If you are inserting into a container from multiple threads, then you need to be using locking. If you aren't that would explain any errors you get.

Comment: Note that reservation of space for buckets only eliminates a small fraction of memory allocations. Each time you insert a new element into hash table, a new node is allocated which is then inserted into a corresponding bucket's linked list. Since all these allocations require same byte sizes, memory pooling may help here a lot. See, e.g., here how to define such a memory-pooled allocator and use it together with `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: Forgot to copy a link: https://github.com/DanielLangr/alloc-bench/blob/master/ht.cpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer to performance related question is - "we should measure".

Here is a benchmark on your code snippet - http://quick-bench.com/O5rEF-B_HY9dOzAa7kLbtptUQcQ